# getting a select is not recognized as an internal or external command when running powershell in docker

Tags: powershell, docker

Trying to troubleshoot an app pool using Docker IIS image. I suspect the application pool identity is to blame and not being set correct

but when i run the code to check, i get an error because the docker container doesnt like my select * for more information

I've tried other cmdlets but they all need a select to find the app pool identity

```
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
        Import-Module WebAdministration; \
        Get-iissite "MyAppPool" ; \
        Get-ItemProperty (IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool | select *) ;
```

> Step 9/11 : RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command         Import-Module WebAdministration;         Get-iissite "MyAppPool" ;         Get-ItemProperty (IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool | select *) ;
>    ---> Running in 80aa407e417d
>   'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: usually a msg like that means the powershell module that contains the `Select-Object` cmdlet is not loading - usually because the account in question does not see the correct module path. have you checked to see that the account has the proper module path?

Answer (score 0):

Try scaping the `*` with one of the following `'`, `"` or `^`.

Hope this solves your issue.